# How to print associative array in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

*my controller is :* **

```
public function getdatewiseOrder()
        {


                $cid        = $this->input->post('cid');
                $startdate  = strtotime($this->input->post('start_date'));
                $enddate    = strtotime($this->input->post('end_date'));

                $order = $this->model_reports->getdatewiseOrder($cid, $startdate, $enddate);
                $x = 0;
                foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
                    $item[$x] = $this->model_reports->getorderItem($value['id']);
                    $x = $x + 1;

                }



                $this->data['order']    = $order;
                $this->data['item']     = $item; 

                $this->render_template('reports/leser_report', $this->data);
        }
```

---

**for check : after print_r of item variable i get data in this format:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [id] => 188 
            [order_id] => 93 
            [product_name] => 2 
            [barcode_nos] => 
            [barcode_no] => 
            [qtykg] => 1 
            [qtypcs] => 2 
            [unit] => 
            [rate] => 234 
            [amount] => 234.00 
            [tax_id] => 
            [timestamp] => 2018-10-30 12:51:10 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [id] => 191 
            [order_id] => 96 
            [product_name] => Small 
            [barcode_nos] => 
            [barcode_no] => 
            [qtykg] => 5 
            [qtypcs] => 5 
            [unit] => 
            [rate] => 100 
            [amount] => 500.00 
            [tax_id] => 
            [timestamp] => 2018-11-15 09:49:41 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [id] => 192 
            [order_id] => 96 
            [product_name] => Medium 
            [barcode_nos] => 
            [barcode_no] => 
            [qtykg] => 5 
            [qtypcs] => 5 
            [unit] => 
            [rate] => 90 
            [amount] => 450.00 
            [tax_id] => 
            [timestamp] => 2018-11-15 09:49:43 
        ) 

    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [id] => 206 
            [order_id] => 105 
            [product_name] => Small 
            [barcode_nos] => 
            [barcode_no] => 
            [qtykg] => 2 
            [qtypcs] => 50 
            [unit] => 
            [rate] => 100 
            [amount] => 200.00 
            [tax_id] => 
            [timestamp] => 2018-11-15 13:38:47 
        ) 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [id] => 207 
            [order_id] => 106 
            [product_name] => Medium 
            [barcode_nos] => 
            [barcode_no] => 
            [qtykg] => 50 
            [qtypcs] => 100 
            [unit] => 
            [rate] => 15 
            [amount] => 750.00 
            [tax_id] => 
            [timestamp] => 2018-11-15 13:40:12 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

I have two tables order and order_item and i am fetch data from both 
for fetching data from order table i use

- $order = $this->model_reports->getdatewiseOrder($cid, $startdate,
  $enddate);

for fetching data from order_item i am using

- $item[$x] = $this->model_reports->getorderItem($value['id']);

  ```
  inside foreach loop
  ```

I want output in this format
                                                                                          [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttNBp.png)

Comment: So you have an array of associative arrays. What's the question?

Comment: Maybe more explanation rather than a bunch of codes. I even tried to edit your post but it's not possible.

Comment: Please add echo `<pre>;` before `print_r()` function used. If you just want to show the item variable

Comment: Also, it depends on that why you want to print the array?

Comment: I want show order details and order item details in view page and i have two table orders and order_item

Comment: My view page html code is like this                      
               <?php  foreach ($item[$x] as $key => $item) { ?>
                          <tr>
                            <td><?= $item[$x]['product_name'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $item[$x]['qtykg'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $item[$x]['qtypcs'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $item[$x]['rate'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $item[$x]['amount'] ?></td>
                          </tr>
                        <?php $x++;} ?>          
                        </table>

Comment: remove the `$x` and just do `$item[] = $this->model_reports->getorderItem($value['id']);`... the numerical index is automatic in controller. then give an example of what you want your output to look like.